# A non-distinct system of representative edges

Tags: graph-theory, perfect-matchings, hypergraph, co.combinatorics, matching-theory

I have the following problem:

Let $ \mathcal{G} = (G_{i})\_{i} $ be a collection of graphs on the same vertex set. I would like to find a "system of representative edges" $ f : \mathcal{G} \rightarrow \bigcup_{i} E(G_{i}) $ such that $ f(G_{i}) \in E(G_{i}) $ and for each $ i, j $ either $ f(G_{i}) = f(G_{j}) $ or $ f(G_{i}) \cap f(G_{j}) = \emptyset $.

In other words, out of each graph we choose one representative edge. Edges $ e_{1} $ and $ e_{2} $ chosen for any two graphs need to either be non-overlapping or identiacal.

This clearly looks very similar to special case of a system of *distinct* representatives for hypergraphs. However, as noted above, in my case the edges need not be distinct.

An even more specialized case of this problem, where each $ G_{i} $ is a biclique naturally emerges when considering CNF formulae (in this case the two partitions contain positive and negative literals respectively).

**Questions:** Has such or similar problem been considered in the literature? What theorems apart from Kőnig's theorem and Hall's marriage theorem could serve as existence criteria or analysis tools for the presented problem.

I will be most grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of the literature on systems of disjoint representatives? It has the same definition as yours, except that $f(G_i)=f(G_j)$ is not allowed. [Here is the classic paper of Aharoni and Haxell: Hall’s theorem for hypergraphs](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Ewhalen/Papers/Hall/matchingsinhyps.pdf).

Comment: One bit of information is that this question is almost a decade old and was posed by a different user.  However, I offer a bounty on it because I had a very similar question and wanted to start by "reviving" this old question before asking my own version of it.  

I am aware of the literature including the paper of Aharoni and Haxell; however, for our purposes it is crucial that we allow for f(G_i)=f(G_j).  I have never seen this variant studied in any way, but it seems natural enough that there's some hope.